# Trying to create a printFactors function in Apple Programming Xcode 8 Swift 3. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: function, loops, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to make the output for this function like this:

> ```
> 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and 6 and 8 and 12 and 24
> ```

but it keeps giving me an error of bad instruction. It should be able to print the factors of any number passed into the function call.

```
func printFactors(number: Int) {
    _ = 0;
    for i in 0...number {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            if (i == 1) {
                print(i)
            } else {
                print(" and ", i)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

also here, I am unsure how to concatenate it so the numbers appear like the sample output. I tried `print (i + " and ")` but this said int and string cannot be combined that way. The above way in the code example is the only way that didn't give me an error.

I am putting this call in the viewdidload but it isn't working. I chose 24 as the parameter but any number should be able to be passed in when the function is called.

```
printFactors(number: 24)
```

I am new to Swift 3 and Apple Programming. Need help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue is that your range `0...number` starts with `0` so you are doing `number % 0` which results in a runtime error for **Division by zero**.

If you want to suppress the newline when printing, then you need to add `, terminator: ""` to your print statements.

`_ = 0;` is a useless statement.

You don't need parenthesis around the test in an `if` statement.

```
func printFactors(number: Int) {
    for i in 1...number {
        if number % i == 0 {
            if i == 1 {
                print(i, terminator: "")
            } else {
                print(" and \(i)", terminator: "")
            }
        }
    }
    print()  // Add a final newline to finish off the line.
}

printFactors(number: 24)
```

Output:

> ```
> 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and 6 and 8 and 12 and 24
> ```